# Prove that $f(x)=2x+[3x]$ is one-one (Where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function)

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that the function $f(x)=2x+[3x]$ defined from $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is one-one

**My try:** For all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\not=y$, I consider two cases

**1)** $[3x]=[3y]$ so we have $f(x)\not=f(y)$

**2)**$[3x]\not=[3y]$ so we have $f(x)\not=f(y)$

I don't know this approach is ok. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would try and show that $f$ is strictly increasing. That is rather easier, and the main claim follows from that immediately. Recall the definition of a strictly increasing function, and you are on your way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $x>y$ we have $3x>3y,2x>2y$ and therefore $[3x]\geq[3y]$ and therefore $2x+[3x]>2y+[3y]$. We got that $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore injective.

Comment: :-)${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach.

$x~$ may be expressed as $~P_x + r_x ~: ~P_x \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r_x < 1.$

Therefore $~f(x)~$ may be expressed as $~2(P_x + r_x) + 3P_x = 5P_x + 2r_x.$

Suppose that $~f(x) = f(y).$

Then

$$~5P_x + 2r_x = 5P_y + 2r_y. \tag1 $$

$\color{red}{\text{Does (1) above imply that}}$
$~P_x = P_y~$ and $~r_x = r_y~?~$

(1) above does imply that

$$5[P_x - P_y] = 2[r_y - r_x]. \tag2 $$

Suppose that (1) above is satisfied, and that (also) $~P_x \neq P_y.$

Then, since $~P_x~$ and $~P_y~$ are **unequal** integers, you must have that $|~5[P_x - P_y]~| \geq 5.$

This implies that

$$|~ 2[r_y - r_x] ~| \geq 5. \tag3 $$

However, (3) above is impossible, because
$~0 \leq r_x,r_y < 1,$ 
which implies that $~|r_y - r_x ~| < 1.$

This implies that $|~ 2[r_y - r_x] ~| < 2,~$ which implies that (3) above can not be satisfied.

Therefore, the simultaneous assumption that

- $f(x) = f(y)$
- $P_x \neq P_y$

has led to a contradiction.

Therefore $~f(x) = f(y)~$ implies $~P_x = P_y,~$ which in turn implies $~r_x = r_y.$

Therefore, $~f(x) = f(y)~$ implies $~x = y.$

Therefore, $~f~$ is a 1-1 function.